# How to make use of the hint for proving $\text{CLT} \implies \text{WLLN}$?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I've seen an exercise where one is asked to prove that the central limit theorem implies the weak law of large numbers. The author gave the following hint: "First prove that convergence in distribution to a constant implies convergence in probability".

After proving the proposition from the hint, I still don't see how it can be useful. I've seen a few proofs of $\text{CLT} \implies \text{WLLN}$ but they didn't go the route from the hint.

Any hints (on how to make use of the hint) are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general result is that if $Z_n→Z$ in distribution and $z_n→0$ then $z_nZ_n→0$ in distribution.